# Laravel Sanctum Prefix returns 404

Tags: laravel, vue.js, csrf, laravel-sanctum

Trying out Laravel 8 (SPA with Sanctum and VueJS) and strangely I cannot get my Vue SPA to make a successful `csrf-cookie` request as shown in the documentation([Laravel - SPA Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating)). I have setup my Vue SPA to use base url as `/api` and I have added `'prefix' => 'api'` in my `config/sanctum.php`. But the request returns a 404 response. If I remove my base url `/api` from my Vue config and send the `csrf-cookie` request, I am getting a success (200) response. Am I missing something ?

Comment: what is your url when set prefix is it api/sanctum/csrf-cookie or api/csrf-cookie?

Comment: It is `/api/sanctum/csrf-cookie`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the prefix overwrite the sanctum prefix so if you wanna set route api/sanctum/csrf-cookie set your prefix api/sanctum. a good way too see that is look at route list by php artisan route:list.

ref: https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/2.x/src/SanctumServiceProvider.php#L81